# Find non existent record in SQL based on a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a couple of tables like below.  Each entry in the TimeEntries table should have one entry per week, with the WeekEnding column being a date, 1 week between each record.  There are times though that someone doesn't have a TimeEntry record for a particular week and I need to find these occurrences.  Any suggestions on how to do this in SQL or Entity Framework?

```
Jobs
  Id [pk]

TimeEntries
  Id [pk]
  JobId [foreign key]
  WeekEnding [DateTime]
```

So for example, I could have the following

```
Id  JobId  WeekEnding
1   1      1/5/24
2   1      1/19/24
3   1      1/26/24
```

So given a date range of 1/1/24-1/31/24, I need to know that the row for 1/12/24 is missing.  Unfortunately, not all rows have the same day of the week that they repeat on.  Some repeat every Friday, some every Sunday, etc.

Comment: You need a calendar table and then you can do a left join to it to find the missing rows.

Comment: What Sean said... also known as a Date Dimension Table when googling it and also that is how some refer to it.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5553/create-an-extended-date-dimension-for-a-sql-server-data-warehouse/

Answer (score 0):

For example, simple recursive query

```
with r as(
  select Id,JobId,WeekEnding,nextEnding,WeekEnding newEntry
      ,0 fNewEntry
    from(select *
           ,lead(WeekEnding,1,WeekEnding)
                over(partition by JobId order by WeekEnding) nextEnding
      from TimeEntries
    )x
  union all
    select 0 Id,JobId,WeekEnding,nextEnding
      ,dateadd(week,1,newEntry) newEntry
      ,case when dateadd(week,1,newEntry)<datetrunc(week,nextEnding) then 1
       else 0
       end fNewEntry
    from r
    where dateadd(week,1,newEntry)<datetrunc(week,nextEnding)
)
select * from r
order by jobid,newEntry
```

| Id | JobId | WeekEnding | nextEnding | newEntry | fNewEntry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-19 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 2024-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-19 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-12 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-01-19 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-26 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-19 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2024-01-26 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-26 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-26 00:00:00.000 | 0 |

If you provide more complex examples in the data, perhaps something will need to be clarified.

Or, output only missing weeks

```
with r as(
  select Id,JobId,dateadd(week,1,WeekEnding) WeekEnding,nextEnding
    from(select *
           ,lead(WeekEnding,1,WeekEnding)
                over(partition by JobId order by WeekEnding) nextEnding
      from TimeEntries
    )x
  where datediff(week,WeekEnding,nextEnding)>1
  union all
  select Id,JobId,dateadd(week,1,WeekEnding) WeekEnding,nextEnding
  from r
  where datediff(week,WeekEnding,nextEnding)>1
)
select * from r
order by jobid,WeekEnding
```

| Id | JobId | WeekEnding | nextEnding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-12 00:00:00.000 | 2024-01-19 00:00:00.000 |

Answer (score 0):

Below Query might help you:

```
Declare @StartDate date, @EndDate date
set @StartDate = '2023-12-05';
set @EndDate = '2024-02-17';

WITH Cte_WeekNoSeries 
AS
(
   select datepart(wk,@StartDate) as weekno, cast(@StartDate as date) as WeekDate
    UNION ALL
    select datepart(wk,WeekDate) as weekno, DATEADD(WW,1,WeekDate) as WeekDate   from Cte_WeekNoSeries  
    where WeekDate < @EndDate
),
Cte_TimeEntries 
AS 
(
    select datepart(wk,WeekEnding) as weekno,  * from TimeEntries
    where WeekEnding between @StartDate and @EndDate
)

select   DATEADD(dd, 5, (DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + CAST(2024 AS VARCHAR)) + (a.weekno-1), 6))) as missing_WeekEnding--, * 
from Cte_WeekNoSeries as a
left join Cte_TimeEntries as b on a.weekno = b.weekno and YEAR(a.WeekDate) = YEAR(b.WeekEnding)
where b.weekno is  null
```